# Can someone help me identify this chip on a robot vacuum?

Tags: microchip, robot, vacuum

It’s on a Rowenta Xplorer series 50, seems like it controls one of the wheel motors and it fried

[image: Full board]

[image: Fried chip]

[image: Left motor chip]

[image: Close up of IC]

Comment: Please upload clear pictures, and consider circling the unidentified IC. It's currently hard to know which IC you're talking about, and what it looks like.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comment, I apologize it didn’t load correctly, you can click on the 4 at the end of my post or here’s a link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JF19s.jpg

Comment: It's very hard to tell what's written on the IC. Please provide a clear picture, or write what you see on it.

Comment: Didn’t even notice there was something written on it, this is the best I could get: https://i.imgur.io/nKAUPQV_d.webp?maxwidth=640&shape=thumb&fidelity=medium

Answer (score 3):

Pinout and function match with Texas Instruments DRV8870.

There is an identical circuit on the opposite side of the board.

Check the shunt resistor at pin 7, should be dead as well.

Probably compatible with Allegro A4950 and Toshiba TB67H451FNG

Comment: From the markings, it's a [TMI TM8870](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2108271830_TMI-TMI8870_C2889167.pdf) which is a DRV8870 clone. [LCSC](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Motor-Driver-ICs_TMI-TMI8870_C2889167.html) has pictures of the markings.

Comment: Thank you very much for the precious information sir, it’s the working one on the picture the dead one (on the left) is all fried, so no more markings visible, I ordered a clone on AE but still can’t find the dead shunt resistor

Comment: The shunt resistor is the big SMD resistor with one side connected to pin 7 of the driver chip. They typically, but not always, burn if such a chip explodes. It is the one hidden behind the electrolytic capacitor on your picture.

Comment: Oh alright, just checked it, it’s fine, I will now wait for the chip and stay positive. Thank you so much Jens